# get position index for all element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

For example

```
mat={{a,b},{c,a,a}}
```

How to write a function `posindex` that `posindex[mat]` will give

```
{{a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}}, {c -> {2, 1}, a -> {2, 2}, a -> {2, 3}}
```

And the function should also work for more complex list, for example

```
{{a,b},{c,{a},a}}
```

What is more, it should also work for elements that are expr, eg

```
{{a,b},{c,{10a},a}}
```

---

**Summary**

I accept Michael E2's answer, because it is by far the only one works for all the above cases and the thought behind the function `elempos` is easy to understand.

kglr's solution has the advantage of using built-in function `MapIndexed`. It works fine for list that contains only atomic expr. But fails when there is both complex level and non-atomic expr. But it is a quite useful solution in many case, what is more it provides level control that `elempos` doesn't have.

Comment: Is this always going to be a nice array?

Comment: @Kuba Oh, good question, If the array is not complex, then it is rather easy. But the general case...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a general solution, according to a generalization that counts an expression as an "element" of a `List` if it is on level 1 of the `List` **and** not inside a function that is not `List`.

```
elempos[expr_] := Module[{mark},
  SetAttributes[mark, Listable];
  Thread[Extract[expr, #] -> #] &@ Position[mark[expr], _mark]
  ]

Clear[f];
e = {{1}, {2, 3}, {4, Sqrt[5], {f[6, {7}]}}, 
     MeijerG[{{I/3}, {}}, {{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, -I]};
elempos[e]
(*
  {1 -> {1, 1}, 2 -> {2, 1}, 3 -> {2, 2}, 4 -> {3, 1}, 
   Sqrt[5] -> {3, 2}, f[6, {7}] -> {3, 3, 1}, 
   MeijerG[{{I/3}, {}}, {{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {}}, -I] -> {4}}
*)
```

Comment: Using `Listable`! So smart! +1

Comment: @matheorem Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

```
MapIndexed[# -> #2 &, mat, {2}]
(* {{a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}}, {c -> {2, 1}, a -> {2, 2}, a -> {2, 3}}} *)
```

or

```
MapIndexed[Rule, mat, {2}] (* thanks: Kuba *)
```

Alternatively,

```
MapIndexed[Rule, mat, {-1}]
(* {{a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}}, {c -> {2, 1}, a -> {2, 2}, a -> {2, 3}}} *)

MapIndexed[Rule, {{a, b}, {c, {a}, a}}, {-1}]
(* {{a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}}, {c -> {2, 1}, {a -> {2, 2, 1}},  a -> {2, 3}}} *)
```

Comment: Ah, of course :) p.s. I find slot-free coding quite nice lately so: `MapIndexed[ Rule, ...]`

Comment: Nice!!! thank you Kuba.

Comment: @kglr I recalled `PositionIndex`, but I forgot `MapIndex`. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @matheorem, thank you for the vote. `PositionIndex` is new-in-v-10; i am still with v9.

Comment: @kglr Now your answer is rather perfect :) Though I have v10, I can't figure out the right way, what a shame!

Comment: @kglr I found another problem when I use this in my work. for example if there is expressions like `{{a, b}, {c, {10a}, a}}`, in this case `{-1}` will treat `10` and `a` separately. Currently, Michael E2's solution is quite good as far as I tested

Comment: Hello, welcome back:)

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
f = Thread[Flatten[#] -> Position[#, _, {-1}, Heads -> False]] &
```

One can probably create example complex enough to fail but let's say it's quite ok :)

```
f[ mat ]
```

> ```
> {a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}, c -> {2, 1}, a -> {2, 2}, a -> {2, 3}}
> ```

Comment: quite good! It also works for `{{a,b},{c,{a},a}}`, your function gives `{a -> {1, 1}, b -> {1, 2}, c -> {2, 1}, a -> {2, 2, 1}, a -> {2, 3}}`. I think this result is good. Though, I have to admit that I didn't think this complex case when I post the question :)