# Mapping at arbitrary nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

This is a candidate for a duplicate (probably from the documentation) but I've ironically failed to find the direct analog so far.

I have an arbitrary nested list, say:

```
anl = {first , second, {x, y, z}, {a, {b, c}}}
```

I need some MMA way to apply `f` to positions `poss` if I do not know them:

```
poss = {{1}, {2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}}
```

So I need 
1) an analog to:

```
MapAt[f, anl, poss]
```

> `{f[first], f[second], {f[x], f[y], f[z]}, {f[a], {f[b], f[c]}}}`

2) a way to get `poss`.

Stuck a bit. Thank you for any constructive help in advance.

Comment: Do you *need* the positions or is something like `anl /. a_Symbol :> f[a] /. f[List] :> List` acceptable?

Comment: @march, I need to operate with leaves of large lists and associations, so positions are not a value in itself. Anyway, Replacement would qualifiy as a useful alternative.

Comment: Is this what you need? `l = Map[f, anl, {-1}];
Most /@ Position[l, f]`?

Comment: related: [99603](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99603/5478)

Comment: @OleksandrR. There is also another topic where someone has extended the answer to take care of non atomic leaves. I think that was Michael E2 but even though I know so much about that topic, I can't find it!

Comment: @Kuba sorry, I can't find it either. (You know you've been in academia too long when you remember who wrote something, but not what it was called!) I thought your suggestion was a good enough duplicate, and OP seems to agree.

Comment: @Kuba This one?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98170/get-position-index-for-all-element-in-a-list/98176#98176

Comment: @Kuba, expression from you post is also valid: `Position[anl, _, {-1}, Heads -> False]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need ? :

```
{result, poss0} = Reap[MapIndexed[(Sow[#2]; f[#1]) &, anl, {-1}]];
poss=poss0[[1]]
result
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}}
>   {f[first], f[second], {f[x], f[y], f[z]}, {f[a], {f[b], f[c]}}}

The level {-1} corresponds to all the leaves of the expression.

Comment: yes, that is what I need. Thank you for `Reap/Sow` solution. Frankly, I thought that some simple function exists that map at all final leaves of the tree.

Comment: @garej yes, it does. You can use `Map[f, anl, {-1}]`. But in your question you wanted the positions of the leaves as well, and I think andre's solution is one of the most obvious ways to get this. Another could be `poss = Level[MapIndexed[f, anl, {-1}], {-2}]`.

Comment: @OleksandrR., you are right, `Map[f, anl, {-1}]` solves a half of the problem and it is up to you to decide (I can edit the post to add the link). I'm glad to get several useful ways of doing this anyway.

Comment: @garej and the other half can be solved with `Level` as also discussed, and as I showed in my comment above. So, if you're happy with it, I'll vote. Please note that questions closed as duplicates will not be deleted: it's just a way to organise the site.

Comment: @Oleksandr R. @garej I don't know if in the OP mind `f` is intended to stay as a simple symbol or is intended to become a more complex expression, for exemple a function like x^2+x+1. In that case the solution `poss=Level[MapIndexed[f,anl,{-1}],{-2}]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

See [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

```
Position[anl, v_ /; ListQ[v] != True, Infinity, Heads -> False]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}} *)
```

Comment: I do not need {4} and {4,2}, and {3}. I've found that positions and manually deleted unneeded =)) And (1) analog would be nice to have.

Comment: See update. Added patter criteria to ignore `List`

Answer (score 3):

```
anl = {first, second, {x, y, z}, {a, {b, c}}};

pos = Position[anl, a_ /; Head@a =!= List, Heads -> False]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}}

Or

```
pos = Position[anl, Except[_List], Heads -> False];

MapAt[g, anl, pos]
```

> {g[first], g[second], {g[x], g[y], g[z]}, {g[a], {g[b], g[c]}}}

I would probably use

```
anl /. a_Except[_List] :> g@a
```